# Kong Authentication for my API application under eks

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kong, kong-plugin, kong-ingress

I have a EKS cluster and i have deployed my api-related microservice applications in my cluster also corresponding services deployed.

emissary is used for ingress controller. In emissary i have a specific Kind: Authservice is used for authentication and which is pointed  to a specific k8s service “auth”. Please find the attached manifest file for the Authservice under emissary.

```
apiVersion: getambassador.io/v3alpha1
kind: AuthService
metadata:
  name: test-auth
spec:
  auth_service: "test-api-auth-service"
  proto: http
  timeout_ms: 5000
  status_on_error:
    code: 403
  path_prefix: "/v1/validate"
  allowed_authorization_headers:
  - "x-test-user-id"
  add_linkerd_headers: false
  failure_mode_allow: true
```

Now i am migrating this applications in another eks cluster and i have migrated the api applications with there corresponding services.But i have used Kong for the ingress controller.I have created a ingress file for routing service “/auth”, and i am able to load. But i want a authservice type of kind in kong showed in above.Please help me to figure out.

Im expecting a proper solution to fix this. i have found multiple authentication plugins in kong, and its still confusing me.So please help me guyz